# Java Game - ClassCastException

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, classcastexception, jscrollbar

I am developing a simple java game and my scrollbar is raising an exception.
The scrollbar is supposed to be a "gameslider".

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.java2d.NullSurfaceData cannot be cast to sun.java2d.d3d.D3DSurfaceData
>       at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DRenderer.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DSurfaceData.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.doCopyArea(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JViewport.blitDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JViewport.windowBlitPaint(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JViewport.setViewPosition(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.hsbStateChanged(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.stateChanged(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValue(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JScrollBar.setValue(Unknown Source)
>       at GameEnvironment.GamePanel.gameUpdate(GamePanel.java:171)
>       at GameEnvironment.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:73)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Code Line is following:

```
        if (reachedMiddle)
        scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(player.getX() - (widthHorizontalScrollBar / 2));
```

The exception will be raised more or less randomly. I didnt figured it out so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make sure this code is run on the GUI Event Thread. If you call the Swing components on other threads you can get strange, randonm errors.

Have a look at using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to perform the tasks where the Swing components are updated.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem. I did it just like in the documentation. 


`Runnable scrollToPlayer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(player.getX() - (widthHorizontalScrollBar / 2));
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(scrollToPlayer);`