# java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.java2d.NullSurfaceData cannot be cast to sun.java2d.d3d.D3DSurfaceData

Tags: java

Please can someone help me on this?

> java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.java2d.NullSurfaceData cannot be
>   cast to sun.java2d.d3d.D3DSurfaceData
>           at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DRenderer.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DSurfaceData.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.doCopyArea(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.RepaintManager.copyArea(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.JViewport.blitDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.JViewport.windowBlitPaint(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.JViewport.setViewPosition(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.vsbStateChanged(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI$Handler.stateChanged(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValue(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.swing.JScrollBar.setValue(Unknown Source)

Comment: Its hard to help you without the code.

Comment: scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(textArea.getHeight() - 20);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Game - ClassCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177943/java-game-classcastexception)

Comment: I have seen this already.But didn't understand anything.Please give clear description.