# Java cannot render Menu state (Java GUI)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, classcastexception

Please read the latest update down below

So I am trying to make a brick breaker game and while everything works in terms of gameplay I am having trouble adding a menu system. Basically this is how my code works

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    public Graphics g;
    private Menu menu;
    protected Ball ball;
    protected Player player;
    protected BufferedImage image;
    protected BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    protected Thread thread;
    protected JFrame frame;
    protected volatile boolean running, gameOver;

private enum STATE{
  MENU,
  GAME,
  ABOUT,
  OPTIONS,
 };
 private STATE State = STATE.MENU;

public Game(){
   //Set the Jframe

}

private void init()
 {
  image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);   
  requestFocus(); 
  menu = new Menu();
  //init everything else aswell
  }
 public void update()
 {
   //Update every moving object 
 }

 @Override
 public void run()
 {
  init();
  
  long initialTime = System.nanoTime();
  double timePerFrame = 1000000000/FPS;
  double delta = 0;
  int ticks = 0;
  long timer = 0;
  while (running)
  {
     long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
     long elapsedTime = currentTime - initialTime;
     delta += elapsedTime/timePerFrame;
     timer += elapsedTime;

     if (delta >= 1)
     {
        update();
        delta--;
        ticks++;
     }

     render();
     initialTime = currentTime;

     if (timer >= 1000000000)
     {
        currentFPS = ticks;
        ticks = 0;
        timer = 0;
     }

  }

  stop();
 }
```

And when I render everything that is in the STATE GAME it works just fine but when I try to add an else if statement that does menu.draw(g) it all falls apart and I just get a blank frame

Here is how I render

```
 public void render()
  {
  bufferStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
  if (bufferStrategy == null)
  {
     createBufferStrategy(3);
     return;
  }

  g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();

  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
  g.setColor(BG_COLOR);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 
  if(State == STATE.GAME){
     player.draw(g);
     ball.draw(g);
     blockController.draw(g); **THESE WORK JUST FINE**
  }
  else if(State == STATE.MENU){
    
     menu.draw(g);  **DOES NOT WORK**

  }

  bufferStrategy.show();
  g.dispose();
  }
```

And my Menu class has no difference in terms of the draw method

```
public class Menu implements GUI
{
  @Override
  public void draw(Graphics g)  {

  g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
  g.setColor(Color.black);
  g.drawString("MENU", Game.WIDTH / 2, 100);
  
  }

}
```

Any idea why this might be happening I am doing the same render litteraly but keep getting
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.java2d.NullSurfaceData cannot be cast to class sun.java2d.d3d.D3DSurfaceData error or g is null error

How can I fix this?

UPDATE ----------------------------------

The menu.draw() in the render works when I remove the lines

```
g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawString("MENU", Game.WIDTH / 2, 100);
```

And instead add something like

```
  g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
  g.fillRect(5, 5, 200, 200);
```

This does work but why the setfont, setColor and drawString don't work I don't understand I wanted to add buttons aswell but they don't work either. Is it because I set the entire frame with a rectangle in the render with the line `g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);` but then can I add objects like paddle,ball,bricks but not a string or a button?

Comment: My first gut feeling is you should evaluate “ Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50)”. As “arial” doesn’t seem like a valid font name, this could cause no text to be rendered

Comment: I’d also recommend looking at the [BufferStrategy JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as they have a really good example of how to use the api

Comment: @MadProgrammer I removed the font line still no sign of life :( Thanks for suggesting the docs tho I will try a loop structre like the one there. My gut is that it has something to do with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177943/java-game-classcastexception but can't understand maybe I will just create new frames for menu and such and then just use the thread if the game actually starts and we need to move stuff

Comment: can it be that I don't use the ticks method in the runnable class maybe I should change the run works so that the ticks have to render it there aswell ? @MadProgrammer

Comment: With a [mcve] it's all just guess work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example seems to work fine.

[image: Menu]

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends Canvas {

        private Thread thread;
        private volatile boolean render = false;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            stop();
        }

        protected void start() {
            if (thread !=  null) {
                render = false;
                try {
                    thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
            render = true;
            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (render) {
                        render();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(16);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }

        protected void stop() {
            render = false;
            if (thread == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            thread = null;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        private Menu menu = new Menu();

        protected void render() {

            BufferStrategy strategy = getBufferStrategy();
            if (strategy == null) {
                createBufferStrategy(3);
                strategy = getBufferStrategy();
            }

            if (strategy == null) {
                return;
            }

            do {
                // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
                // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
                do {
                    // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
                    // to make sure the strategy is validated
                    Graphics graphics = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
                    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                    menu.render(graphics, getSize());

                    graphics.dispose();

                    // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
                    // were restored
                } while (strategy.contentsRestored());

                // Display the buffer
                strategy.show();

                // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
            } while (strategy.contentsLost());
        }

    }

    public class Menu {

        public void render(Graphics g, Dimension bounds) {
            // This is probably going to cost you a lot of
            // performance and it might be better to 
            // pre-create the font instead
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            String text = "MENU";
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();

            g.drawString("MENU", (bounds.width - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2, (bounds.height / 2) - fm.getAscent());
        }

    }
}
```

If you continue to have issues, continue providing a runnable example which demonstrates your issue